# Encoding Extreme #6

Tags: cipher

While I was in school this morning, I found a way to encode text... *unusually*.

In 15 minutes, I drew this sketch:

```
1 ~ * ¬ +*-*++*+* ¬
5 ~ *+*-----*++++++* ¬
4 ~ *++++*+*++*+*
1 ~ *+++++++*+++++*
#!

1i/2l/3k/4e/5t/6h/7s/8n/9c/o+1/d+2/g+3
```

What does the sketch say? Also, explain how to decode it.

Comment: I think you messed something up in line 2. Think I figured it out.

Comment: @z-dailey Thanks for reporting! Fixing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This took a minute of looking at cuz there was a small issue.

> I like this encoding!

How I found the answer:

> Starting with 1 you get 'I' from the key. Then add 1 you get 'L' subtract 1 you get 'I' add 2 you get 'K' etc. 
>  `1 ~ * ¬ +*-*++*+* ¬`
>  I like
>  `5 ~ *+*-----*++++++* ¬`
>  This
>  `4 ~ *++++*+*++*+*`
>  Encod
>  `1 ~ *+++++++*+++++*`
>  Ing
>  `#!`
>  ! 
>  ¬ --> space and # --> punctuation.

Comment: You forgot saying what the ¬ does ;)

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I was thinking space, but it's missing one if its a space.

Comment: Right! I forgot one of those. Thanks!

Comment: Put in the edits. :)